# Why does anchor tag remove tab character in URL specified inside href attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

`Anchor tag` is removing `tab character` in `URL` specified inside `href attribute` which is calling `Javascript function` in my case whereas if spaces are present in `URL` specified inside `href attribute` it won't remove

Below is the sample piece of code to reproduce it-

```html
<html>
<script>
function test(name)
{
 alert(name+ "is the Name");
}
</script>
<body>
<a href="Javascript:test('Murlidhar ');">Click Me</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `test('Murlidhar\t')`

Comment: the question is good because of the uri trim but the whole idea is just not constructive, if tab is needed test should care of it not the other way around

Comment: my problem is the value which I am passing to Javascript:test() function is a string coming from server. to illustrate the issue I have just hard coded it in this sample code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an [`<a>` element is clicked](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics.html#links-created-by-a-and-area-elements), the link is [*followed*](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics.html#follow-hyperlinks) and its URL is [*resolved*](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#resolving-urls). This causes the string to be processed by the [basic URL parser](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-basic-url-parser).

In your example, the parameter is processed in the [path state](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#path-state) during which TAB (U+0009) characters, along with carriage return and line feed characters, are ignored, and therefore do not form part of the resolved URL.

Only then is the resolved URL evaluated, the "javascript:" scheme recognised and the remainder handed off to the script engine for processing.

Answer (score 4):

The content of an `href` attribute is *always* an URI. URIs do not allow whitespace, so the browser strips it. You can overcome this problem by %-encoding the tab (and any other spaces):

```
Space -> %20
Tab -> %09
Line feed (\n) -> %0A
```

Comment: But OP says  _if spaces are present in URL specified inside href attribute it won't remove_ .. are spaces  not considered whitespace?

Comment: Likely browser dependant. I know older versions of IE would keep the spaces. The above is the correct way to do it though, even if *sometimes* the browser keeps the whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Like Boldewyn said. URI's Don't accept whitespaces. try `\t` to have space after the name in `text()`.